# How do I make a task sync up with UTC time and run every 6 hours discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to sync up my task with my task which clears a channel every 6 hours of all it's messages.
I have this code which runs every hour synced up with the UTC time (e.x] it runs at 1:00pm and then it runs agane at 2:00 pm regardless when I i start the script) but now I want to make it so that the script runs every 6 hours at(12:00am, 6:00am, 12:00pm, 6:00pm)UTC and I tryed but, I cant seem to figure it out.Pls help me with this.Thanks before hand.

Code:

```
    import discord
    import os
    import asyncio
    from discord.ext import commands,tasks
    from datetime import datetime


    class Events(commands.Cog):

     def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

     @tasks.loop(hours=1)
     async def bot_test_clear(self):
       channel_bot_test = self.client.get_channel(os.getenv('bot-test-text'))
       messages = await channel_bot_test.history(limit=100).flatten()

       if not messages:
         return
    
       embed = discord.Embed(description='It has been 1 hour, clearing chats...', color=0xff0000)
       await channel_bot_test.send(embed=embed)
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
       await channel_bot_test.purge(limit=None) 

    @bot_test_clear.before_loop()
    async def prep(self):
      now = datetime.utcnow()
      future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour +1,0)
      delta = (future - now).total_second()

      print(round(delta/60))
      await asyncio(delta)

  

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
      self.bot_text_clear.start()

      print(f'{self.client.user} is now online')

  def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Events(client))
```

Comment: This is what you want (https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/) I use it for my bot too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've answered your previous question which the code is based on, I'll attempt to answer this one too.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@tasks.loop(hours=6)
async def bot_test_clear(self):
    ...


@bot_test_clear.before_loop
async def prep(self):
    hour, minute = 12, 00  # 12:00 am, change accordingly

    now = datetime.utcnow()
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)

    if future < now: # if time is in the past
        future += timedelta(days=1)  # delay to the next day

    delta = (future - now).total_second()
    await asyncio.sleep(delta)


bot_test_clear.start()  # you don't need to start it in the on_ready event
```

The code is really similar, the only thing changed is the hour and minute passed into the datetime constructor.

Comment: do i need to change the 1 hour to 6 at @tasks.loop()?

Comment: yes, change it accordingly to the hour you want it to start.

Comment: Also change the delay of the task to 6 hours instead of 1.